# Как сделать так чтобы скачивался в самом телеграм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Я написал бота для скачивания музыки на языке python и с помощью pyTelegramBotApi, подключил библиотеку youtube-dl для скачивания видео с YouTube дальше просто меняет формат на mp3. Тут понятно что скачивается в памяти носителя (в мой ноут) это легко решаемо просто очищать за собой. Вопрос в том, а какие есть способы чтобы скачивался в самом телеграм боте. Например я отправляю ссылку на видео боту а он скачивает прям на глазах если можно так выразиться). Хороши пример этот телеграм Бот https://t.me/SaveYoutubeBot

Comment: он будет скачивать на ту машину, на которой он запущен. Если запущен на ноуте - будет скачивать на ноут. Если арендуете сервер и запустите его там, то будет скачивать на сервер...Но за место и там и там придется платить.

Comment: Если вы про тот бот который я оставил в качестве примера, но я хотел бы узнать как он работает изнутри

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, вы можете использовать [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) чтобы миновать создание файла и использовать данные напрямую. Прочитайте документацию, там много интересного :)
Что-то подобное на:

```
f = io.BytesIO(your_binary_data_here)
bot.send_video(chat_id, video=f) # вместо video=open('output.mp4', 'rb')
```

Comment: ответ очень хороши, но из-за того что я начинающий в изучений Python не могу понять как использовать его правильно. используя Youtube-dl эти строки`with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:` `ydl.download([url])` скачивают на диск, а как мне стоит написать чтобы скачивался в ОП и в дальнейшем мог работать с ним например отправить в телеграмбот